# How implement render logic with promise inside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I begin read in React.js and faced with occurred. I make get request to the server, in the answer is get json file. I is parse this json and since this promise is return the fulfilled, should start 'then', but my renderRoomList() nothing return and i get error. How to implement logic correctly? Func 'renderRoomList' should return to the render, only after get data from server

```
load() {
    var result = []
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       fetch('url', {method: 'GET'})
       .then(response => {
            if(response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw new Error('error');
            }
        })
        .then(//parsed json and add to result array)
    };
    promise.then(() => {
            return(<div>{result}</div>)
        }
    return //what return?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning JSX from the promise, you could use `setState` to set the `result` in your component state, and use `this.state.result` in the render method instead.

**Example**

```js
function getData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("foobar");
    }, 1000);
  });
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { result: "" };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.load();
  }

  load = () => {
    getData().then(result => {
      this.setState({ result });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.result}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks behind you suggestion